# Calling Odata Service Put method C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am trying to use the PUT method to update an record using the Odata services. Below is the code for doing it

```
 private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PutJsonAsync(string messageBody,string B_Code)
 {
 string userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"];
 string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
 string BaseURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURL"];

 try
 {
   using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
   {
       var request = new StringContent(messageBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
       string apiUrl = "SAM('" + B_Code + "')";
       request.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
       request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("If-Match", "*");
       var url = string.Format("{0}{1}", BaseURL, apiUrl);
       var creds = userName + ":" + password;
       var credentials = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(creds);
       httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(credentials));

       response = await httpClient.PutAsync(new Uri(url), request);
   }
  }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
   throw ex;
 }
 return response;
  }
```

I am setting the header If-Match it is required for this PUT method to work. 
[image]
But the when I am debugging it throws error response 501 in the response

`response   {StatusCode: 501, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Implemented', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:

  OData-Version: 4.0
  Date: Mon, 30 Oct 2017 20:42:28 GMT
  Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=XYZ; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
  Set-Cookie: XYZ;PATH=/;SECURE;HTTPONLY
  Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Connection: keep-alive
  Content-Length: 277
  Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal
}}  System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage`

But trying the same PUT method in the POSTMAN works without any error. Verified the messageBody is the valid JSON. Not sure what could be the issue.

Comment: Hmm kind of shot in the dark, but could it be because you have `private`, instead of `public`?

Comment: I suggest using Fiddler to compare your request against the successful one from Postman. You will probably find a difference between them.

Comment: I suspect issue with your URL generated from code.

Comment: @I checked the URL and looksfine

Comment: @JLRishe testing the request in Fiddler looks complex. If it is Postman it should be working in the above code as well right.

Comment: @xyz How would I know? Maybe you're missing something or something isn't quite right. There's nothing complex about using Fiddler for this. You send the request from Postman, you send the request from C#, then look at them side-by-side to see what differs.

Comment: @Found the issue is `IF-Match` in the headers. How should I set that up in the headers `request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("If-Match", "*");` is not working

Comment: @xyz _"not working"_ What does that mean? What's the issue?